# ORACLE data base custom tablespace files

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a task to create an Oracle DataBase with custom tablespace files

Tablespace `SYSTEM` files location:

```
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node03/uyomi4.dbf.
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node04/ikete45.dbf.
```

Tablespace `SYSAUX` files location:

```
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node03/zej95.dbf.
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node02/vig46.dbf.
```

Tablespace `USERS` files location:

```
/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node01/ujuzala626.dbf
```

this is my script for database creation:

```
CREATE DATABASE leftsoup
    MAXDATAFILES 100
    CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
    NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16
    EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSTEM
         DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node03/uyomi4.dbf'
         SIZE 100M REUSE,
         DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node04/ikete45.dbf'
         SIZE 100M REUSE
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSAUX 
          DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node03/zej95.dbf' 
          SIZE 100M REUSE,
          DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node02/vig46.dbf'
          SIZE 100M REUSE
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
          DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node01/ujuzala626.dbf'
          SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
```

I got error 
ORA-12950: SYSTEM tablespace specified as default permanent tablespace

Please, help! And,check other for probably more mistakes:

```
DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSTEM
     DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node03/uyomi4.dbf'
     SIZE 100M REUSE,
     DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node04/ikete45.dbf'
     SIZE 100M REUSE
DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSAUX 
      DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node03/zej95.dbf' 
      SIZE 100M REUSE,
      DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node02/vig46.dbf'
      SIZE 100M REUSE
DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
      DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/leftsoup/node01/ujuzala626.dbf'
      SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
```

Thanks anyone!

Comment: Have you bothered to search on the internet?  A google query shows: If default permanent tablespace is not specified,then SYSTEM will implicitly become the default permanent tablespace. Specify an alternate tablespace or omit the default tablespace clause and reissue the CREATE DATABASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use SYSTEM tablespace for TEMPORARY tablespace ... doesn't that make sense ? One is the most vital tablespace in the database, the other is the most unnecessary tablespace in the database.